# How do i clear data of multiple collections in mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created a copy of 1 DB to another. I want only the blank collections in that newly created DB.
I just want blank collections in that created DB. How can i do that?
Is their any script or any query related to this?
Please tell me the query or script related to it.

Comment: This has some useful info: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259827/clone-collection-in-mongodb-in-the-same-db

Answer (score 1):

In that case you don't need to create collections. When you will create a document, collection will be automatically created.